# I am trying to use masked url in htaccess and now i am not able to get search queries in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, search, methods

I am creating a website in php and using htaccess rewrite rule. My htaceess codes to hide core php page is

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} search
RewriteRule search /directory/search.php?&q=$1
```

---

I am using method GET in from to submit queries and form is

---

```
<form action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/search" method="GET">
<span><input type="text" name="q" class="search rounded" placeholder="Search something... :)" x-webkit-speech speech onwebkitspeechchange="this.form.submit();"></span>
</form>
```

---

my temporary code for search.php is

---

```
<?php

if(!isset( $_GET['q']))
    {
        echo '<p>Page is not set!</p>';
    }
        else
        {
            echo '<p>Search Page is running cool';
        }
?>
```

---

when i search in form like i am searching word "hello" it shows me url "localhost/search?q=hello"

the other thing is i am getting "internal server error 500"

I am using xampp and i think my htaccess is not working properly first and then search form is not sending proper queries and all. so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is a GET request type.

Need to pass the parameter to the initial rewrite variable.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/$ /directory/search.php?&q=$1 [L]
```

To POST data, not GET:

```
RewriteRule ^search /directory/search.php?q=$1 [NC,P]
```

"P" acts like "L" in that it stops processing rules but it also tells the module that the request should be passed off to the proxy module intact (meaning POST data is preserved).

Also, make sure you turn the rewrite engine on, and set your options. 
without the rewrite engine on, it will give you a 500 error.

This is what I typically use:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 300 /error.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: i tried for post method, i added post rewrite rule in htaccess file, and also added "Options..." in htaccess but in url it is showing me localhost/search nothing else and showing me same error of 500 and also tried get method and same 500 error, but in url i am getting search?q=hello